# Android data storage for plotting graph

Tags: java, android

In my android application, i need to plot a graph showing the last 2 hours of data updated in 30 second interval.

Also I would like to update the data on the file. At any time, the data file should contain only the most recent 2 hours of data. What is the best way for it since after two hours, every second a data element has to be removed from the top of the file and new data added to the bottom of the file and the file data should start from the first line.

Can someone suggest me, the best way to store data. So that i can read simultaneously from it and plot it at the same time.

Comment: What kind of / how much data are we talking about? i.e. per entry how much data is stored?

Comment: Accelerometer data by any chance?

Comment: where are you storing the data ..... and what id the data like your are storing it in database or in Collection class ......

Comment: :) That is the question that i have. I still have not implemented it. I was thinking of storing in a csv file. @lain_b: Its barometer data. I would like your suggestion on it

Comment: I wrote an app where I stored accelerometer data in an array list (as per my answer below ) so long as the amount of data isn't so large, and yours won't be, it works fine. It's also really easy to implement.

Comment: I was not planning to use any array list as the application can go in the background or it can die. If i am using an array list, i will have to store all these  values in bundle and retrieve. Is that a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need 120*2 = 240 entries at any one time and each entry is only 12 bytes (3 floats). I would just use array lists.

```
ArrayList<Float> dataX = ArrayList<Float>();//for one of the three floats
```

then to add new entry

```
if( dataX.getSize() < 240 ){
    dataX.add( value );
}else{
    dataX.remove(0);//remove oldest
    dataX.add( value );
}
```

The above might need some tweaking, consider it pseudo code.

[edit] you could change the type of the list to Float[] and store all three sets of floats in one array list but you might like to be able to access each set of data independently, I don't know.